# question about using ARM pseudo-instruction UND

Tags: arm, armcc

I am trying to generate a undefined instruction by using pseudo-instruction mentioned in http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armasm/armasm_dom1361289918908.htm

My inline assembly code like below:

```
__asm volatile ("UND 0xe7f000f0")
```

However I got this error:

```
Error:  #3061: unrecognized instruction opcode
```

To me seems like UND is not recognized as no matter how I play with the 0xe7f000f0 value part , always show this error, would like to know if anyone tried the UND instruction and what might be wrong in my inline assembly?

Comment: Presumably this macro is not available with embedded assembly, simple as that.